# Checkbox checked state not changing in JQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm creating an MVC4 project with `JQuery Mobile` UI.

This is my login form:

[image: Login Form]

and this is my `<form>` in my html:

```
    <form action="/Account/Login/" method="post">
    <ul>
        <li>
            @Html.Label("User name:")
            @Html.TextBox("userName")
        </li>

        <li>
            @Html.Label("Password")
            @Html.Password("password")
        </li>
        <li>
            <input type="checkbox" name="rememberme" id="remember" />
            <label for="remember">Remember me</label>
        </li>
        <li>
            <input type="submit" value="Login" />
            @{if (ViewBag.LoginFailed)
              {
                <br />
                <b style="color: red;">Username and/or password was not correct. please try again.</b>
              }
            }
            <br />
            <br />
            Not registered? <a href="/Account/Register">Click here</a> to create an account!
        </li>
    </ul>
    </form>
```

My problem is: when I click on `Remember me` label or the checkbox, checkbox still remains unchecked...

How to solve this issue??

---

**Edit:** [This](http://safebin.net/8193) is the complete output html from mvc, [This](http://safebin.net/8194) is my style.css file, and [this](http://safebin.net/8195) is the generated code in DOM.

(My project is changed since one month ago, so these outputs are a little different from the screenshot. But the checkbox still doesn't work...)

Comment: I drew up a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4Bgx7/1527/) based on your sample code, minus the html helpers and the checkbox works fine. I noticed that in your screenshot the checkbox looks disabled. Do you have some other piece of code which is altering it in any way?

Comment: As Alejo says, I set up a jsbin with your code and it works no problem. I'm almost certain that another part of the code is interfering with the checkbox. Can you post your CSS ? Could you also post the code for the checkbox taken directly from the dom (i.e. after it has been enhanced by jquery mobile).

Comment: This question asked many time ago, and now some things are changed in my page. but still the checkbox doesn't work. I'll update question with requested details in the next few minutes.

Comment: Question updated with requested details.

Comment: your update give us an output file. I copied it in jsfiddle and it worked too. the problem isn't from `HTML`, `JaueryMobile` or another programming tools. I think it's because of your system. (I updated my answer too!)

Comment: ahmadali's fiddle doesn't work in my computer. And I had this problem in two computers (one Windows 7 and the other Windows 8). Currently I have Google Chrome 21.0.1180.60 on Windows 7 Machine, And one month ago, I had a Windows 8 Machine, But I don't remember the version of google chrome of that machine. **And, the fiddle that Alejo provided is working perfectly in my computer.**

Answer (score -1):

I tried it just now with [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gKLd7/) and we know that Asp.Net MVC doesn't change HTML tags in output. But I also tried it in an MVC4 application and it worked. You can see the result [here](http://tests.ahmadalli.net/cb/).

Your browser may has some problem with `jquery mobile` and if you are using chrome you can see the errors (if exist) using development tools of google chrome (to open it right click on page and click on `inspect element`).

**update**

your update give us an output file. I copied it in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GZPFa/) and it worked too. the problem isn't from `HTML`, `JqueryMobile` or another programming tools. I think it's because of your system.

Comment: **You are just saying that my problem doesn't really exists.** It is not a good answer to a question... (My problem exists so I asked it here) Also I'm using Google Chrome 21 and there is just one error in inspect element: `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://localhost:2191/Includes/images/icons-18-white.png` which tells that an image is missing and should not affect the functionality of checkbox...

Comment: @MahdiGhiasi I'm telling that with the situations that you told us the problem doesn't exist. I'm telling you may give us more details or with this details, yes the problem doesn't exist.